# 'Save As' of object '_workbook' failed

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error

I am trying to save a workbook as xlsm, this is the code I use:

```
ThisWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="path\workbook_name.xlsm", FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled
```

I have done some testing, and It does in fact **save in both a private folder and a public or shared folder**
however when I save it in a shared folder I also get this:

> Run-time error '1004' Method 'Save As' of object '_workbook' failed

why do I get error message when it is saved in a public/shared folder, or onedrive?

Answer (score 0):

In your string containing path there is variable "path" i suppose. Then you should write it like this:

```
Dim path as String:       path = "C:\Users\xxx\Desktop"
ThisWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=path & "\workbook_name.xlsm", FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled
```

Or you can hardcode full path (*but i recommend using variables - first example*).

```
ThisWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\file.xlsm", FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled
```

Comment: Sorry, path is not the actual path I use, I use a specific path which is of the form "C:\Users\xxx\Desktop", and I do manage to save it in the folder, but the error message still appears.

Like I mention, I do manage to save it in a private folder without the error message appearing, but when I save it in a public folder or via onedrive (C:\Users\xxxx\OneDrive\.....) then it does also save, but with an error message saying that it failed. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Then when you can save it manually and you have permissions then i have no idea since i normally save files to shared folders and network drives... Maybe your specific path is wrong. It is best to save using servername and folders...

```
path = "\\servername\folder1\folder2\workbook_name.xlsm"
```

Because sometimes when you refefer to mapped drive for example X:\folder2 then you must ensure that all users have it mapped in same way (someone uses X someone uses R etc.). And if path is correct then only other way i can think of it is permission issue, but if you can save it manually then i have sadly no idea... :)